# Node.js Twitter library that supports update_with_media

Tags: node.js, twitter

None of the libraries I have tried support **update_with_media** for posting images:

- [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)
- [node-twitter-api](https://npmjs.org/package/node-twitter-api)
- [node-twitter](https://github.com/istrategylabs/node-twitter)

All of these libraries *claim* to implement this functionality, which is very worrying.

If anyone is currently running software that is doing this, please reply. I am not interested in URL's linking to software that claims to support this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was searching for same thing for a while with little success.
So I decided to make my own which turned out to be short and sweet:

https://gist.github.com/adaline/7363853

All the instructions are in the gist :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I was having a hard time finding a library that actually worked.

Answer (score 2):

I modified @Val's gist to support files from remote url's (i.e. s3) rather than reading it from a file. Thought I'd share in case it's useful to others. https://gist.github.com/travischoma/9279105